# Is sys.path.append() a good workaround?

Tags: python, structure, python-import

I am seeing some of my colleagues use the following workaround for importing external python modules (without installing them).

```
import sys

sys.path.append(<PATH_TO_MODULE>)
import <module>
sys.path.remove(<PATH_TO_MODULE>)
```

I don't think this is a good approach but "it works".
What should I suggest them to do instead of the following code and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to install them?

Comment: We have different teams developing those libs but currently they can't provide an "installable" package. Plus, right now we don't have someone to take care of that in a centralized way (neither a DevOps person/routine).

Comment: You don't need a devops team to create an installable package. Just add a simple `setup.py` file and `pip install -e` it in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though your colleagues are not making [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to run python and are trying to avoid muddy-ing the main python modules.

So I'd suggest they start seperating out their concerns and projects into seperate virtual environments where they don't need to worry about having modules installed.

<sub>See also conda environments and other alternatives to achieve the same goal</sub>

Comment: Or put another way, from the script's perspective the module *is* installed, just not somewhere that will disturb other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to append the module’s path to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/module/"
```

In this way, nothing is hardcoded in your source code and whenever something changes, you just need to export the new path to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Isn't this the same as they are doing? (with the exception of adding the path in the OS and not in the Python code)

Comment: @DanielLima It does the same thing but as I said, you don't have to hardcode any paths to your source code which most of the times is a bad practise.